# Why do I get "can't copy file" error at some point after starting partitioning?

Tags: installation, livedvd

I have the DVD version of 12.04, which I tried to install on my Lenovo machine with a Core i3 processor.

It's working on live mode but when I tried to install to my hard drive it after telling it what partitions to use it fails with a "can't copy file" error. The error also had some number associated with it--I believe it was "error 3" or "error 5" but I don't remember.

I also tried making a bootable pendrive but it shows same error. After this I tried the CD version of 11.10 is install and its successfully done.

Why can't I install from the DVD version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure this is actually happening *while partitioning*, rather than *after partitioning*? If the error message really says "cannot copy file," that's *most likely* to occur *while installing* (specifically, while *copying files* from the DVD to already-created partitions on the hard disk).

You haven't given us much information, but most problems copying files while installing are the result of bad installation media. So:

- [MD5 test the `.iso` image you used to create the DVD.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM)
- [Check the DVD for defects in the machine on which you're attempting to install.](http://zootlinux.blogspot.com/2010/05/check-disc-for-defects-in-ubuntu-1004.html)

Since you created both DVD media and USB media from the DVD `.iso` image and got what you believe to be the same error, **it's most likely the `.iso` image itself is what's bad** (so the MD5 test will reveal the problem and you can re-download the DVD `.iso`).

- If you download a new `.iso` image, MD5 test it, and find it's corrupted as well, you might try downloading via torrent, since the BitTorrent protocol checks for (and fixes) corruption as it's downloading. You mentioned that you had a similar problem installing at least one other OS (Backtrack). Most other operating systems also have MD5 hashes (or similar) available, and you can check to see if those downloads are corrupted in the same way.

However, if the MD5 test doesn't reveal errors, you should still check the installation media for defects. You may have two separate, defective writes, or a subtle hardware problem in the machine on which you're installing.

If this happens with other `.iso` images, even if it includes `.iso` images for other OSes, it's still worth running those tests, as there may be a systematic problem (for example, with your Internet connection) causing you to download corrupted `.iso` files. There may also be a systematic problem (perhaps with your technique) causing them to be written and/or burned incorrectly.

Depending on the nature of a hardware problem, doing "Check disc for defects" (which applies to USB media as well as actual CD/DVD *discs*) may fail due to a hardware problem on the computer on which you perform it. That can be good, in that in combination with other information, it can make it possible to diagnose a hardware problem.

It also **might be** that, due to a problem downloading images, burning/writing them, or **a problem with the computer on which you're installing**, *all* installations have a high chance of failure, and that your one installation succeeded more due to luck than due to it being a different ISO image and installation medium.

Comment: @bugsbunny I've expanded my answer above to address this question.

Comment: Thank u Eliah . MD5 test is usefull and You right its seems in  defect in iso image. so than k u very much. and keep helping people like this

Comment: @bugsbunny I'm glad I could help. You should redownload the `.iso` file and MD5 the new image to make sure it's good. If you find you keep downloading corrupted ISO images you might try downloading via torrent, since the BitTorrent protocol checks for (and fixes) corruption *as it's downloading*. Most other operating systems, including Backtrack, also have MD5 hashes (or similar) available, and you can check to see if those downloads are corrupted in the same way. *If you consider this answer to have solved your problem, please accept it by clicking the gray check mark to the left of it.*